# Wordpress Sticky menu on mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

I need help with my mobile menu in WordPress site, as you can see in this print screen: https://monosnap.com/file/2tp8pIR2f2zql8hr6MT0IPKQvt1MTG menu doesn´t show after scrolling in mobile.

It can be checked here https://unmaze.io

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a detailed traceback?

Comment: you can touch and scroll in mobile on left side. seems you are trying in browser.